# Read string1 within string2 and count occurences of string1 in string2

Tags: c, string

I have to write a function in C that counts the occurences of a string "mystring" within an input string.

The user will input a string containing the phrase "mystring" with no spaces anywhere in the string and the program will count how many times "mystring" is read within the input string.

Here is the code I have written so far but it is not working properly.

```
int substr_count(char *srcString, char *subString)
{
    int i = 0;  // counter variable
    int countOccurence = 0;   

    while(srcString[i] != 0)        // loop until hit a null in srcString
    {
        if (srcString[i] == subString[i])
        {
            countOccurence++;
        }
        i++;    // increment to next position in srcString
    }
    return countOccurence;      // return value of occurences
}

int main(void)
{
  char srcString[200] = "";  //empty string
  char subString[8] = "mystring";  //substring
  int get_count = 0;

  scanf("%s", srcString); //get a string from input keyboard

  get_count = substr_count(srcString, subString);

  printf("%s occurs %d times in %s\n", subString, get_count, srcString);
}
```

Comment: 1) `char subString[8] = "mystring";` --> `char subString[] = "mystring";` or `char subString[9] = "mystring";`

Comment: 2) `while(srcString[i] != 0)        // loop until hit a null in srcString
    {
        if (srcString[i] == subString[i])
        {
            countOccurence++;` This is wrong logic.

Comment: You can use `strstr`.

Comment: @izzleskizzle  If the inputted string consists only from the substring then the counter of occurrences of the substring is equal to strlen( srcString ) / strlen( substring ).:)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY how do I implement `strstr` to return a number of occurences?

Comment: I posted sample to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [strstr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int substr_count(const char *srcString, const char *subString){
    int countOccurence = 0;
    size_t sub_len = strlen(subString);
    const char *p = srcString;

    while(p = strstr(p, subString)){//if NOT NULL, found it
        ++countOccurence;
        p += sub_len;//set next search point
    }
    return countOccurence;
}

int main(void){
    char srcString[200] = "";
    char subString[] = "mystring";//const *char subString = "mystring"
    int get_count = 0;

    scanf("%199s", srcString);//199 : Set limits
    get_count = substr_count(srcString, subString);

    printf("%s occurs %d times in %s\n", subString, get_count, srcString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems in your code:

1. Declaring a string or an array?

    A string is a contiguous chunk of char with an ending '\0' null terminator, while an array is a contiguous chunk of element with the same type.


    It is very important to know that between string literal (everything between `" "`) always have one more element than how it looks.

    `"haha"` contains 5 chars, 'h', 'a', 'h', 'a', '\0'

    `""` contains 1 char, '\0', even if it looks like empty.



    The null terminator charactor do make the difference. all standard string functions will now work if you pass in an array or char.


    So you should either declare your `subString` as undefined amount of element initialised to "mystring" (`char subString[] = "mystring";`)

    or you can declare your subString as an array of 9 elements, with the last element as a null terminator (`char subString[9] = "mystring";`)
2. your scanf is not defined.

    Please include "stdio.h> at the top of the file.

*removed due to some mistakes in my answer*

---

*Fixed a few things, thanks for pointing out my mistakes*

Comment: 4) There seems to be a case where subString malfunctions in case of repetition like `mymymy`.

Comment: `fgets(srcString, 199, stdin);` --> `fgets(srcString, 200, stdin);` or `fgets(srcString, sizeof srcString, stdin);` It is not necessary to **-1**.

Comment: hmm I tested it in my compiler and repetition seems fine

Comment: `mymy occurs 5 times in mymymymymymy` : The search area overlaps. If there is no overlap, the result is 3

Comment: E.g I said "mymymymymymy". How many times I said "mymy"? That is three times. It is not five times.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY had a breakfast and realised I have so many errors, thank you for looking thru my answer and point out my mistakes, I had also learnt a lot from you!